# Last step in proving $\pi_1(S^n) = 0$ for $n > 1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

> [image]

This is an adaption from Hatcher, but basically I am confused about the last step. After we conclude $f^{-1}(x) \subset \cup_{i < m} (a_i,b_i)$. How do we conclude $f(a_i), f(b_i)$ is on the boundary? And I am confused about creating this loop $g$ from the partition.

Also just curious, does the definition of a loop include "inner loops". Let $x_0$ be the based point. [image]

Answer (score 0):

If $f(a_i), f(b_i)$ are not in the boundary of $B$, just shrink $B$.

Comment: If we shrink $B$, what if we shrink so small that we go past the point $x$?

Comment: $x$ is in the interior of $B$ and you make finitely many moves since you have a finite number of intervals $f([a_i,b_i])$ contains $x$, so you can shrink $B$ and $x$ remains in the interior of $f([a_i,b_i])$.

Comment: So we are just taking the particular $f(a_i,b_i)$ that contains $x$? So by defining $g = f_i: [a,b] \to \bar{B}$, isn't this path not connected because we miss the values in the interior of $B$ right?

Comment: the image of a connected set is connected

Comment: Sorry I thought it was $g : [a,b] \to \partial B$, u are right.  But now I don't understand why $g$ would miss $x$. The interval $(a_i,b_i)$ was chosen to contain $f^{-1}(x)$ right?

Comment: it wont miss $x$.

Comment: But $g$ maps to the boundary of $\bar{B}$, so it misses $x$ in the interior.